# How to get the unmatched head/tail of a string before/after all the RegEx matches

Tags: python, regex

If my string is

`firsthead -var1 val1 -var2 val2 -varN valN thensometail`

AND

my RegEx pattern to capture the repeating `-<varname> <varval>` pattern is

```
-([^\s]+)?\s([^\s]+)?\s
```

(had to use `[^\s]` as opposed to `(\w+)` because the latter excludes ., which can be part of the var/val, basically anything but an empty space can be part of the var name and value)

AND

I used `re.findall` to find all the repeating matches of the above pattern

How do I extract the head of the string (`firsthead`) and tail (`thensometail`) before and after the captured matches respectively?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know all the formats of your strings, so the following statements only suit the string that you have mentioned:

```
>>> test = 'firsthead -var1 val1 -var2 val2 -varN valN thensometail'
>>> exp = r"([^\s])+\s(-\S+\s\S+\s)+([^\s])+"
>>> re_exp = re.compile(exp)
>>> res = re_exp.search(test).group().split()
>>> head = res[0]
>>> tail = res[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the original string is stored in `stringyThingy` and the (nonempty) results of the `re.findall` are in `allFound`:

```
firsthead = stringyThingy[:allFound[0].start()]
thensometail = stringyThingy[allFound[-1].end():]
```